# Stack Overflow Error in Xamarin Android app's OnCreate

Tags: xamarin.android

I just ran into a weird problem. I have a Xamarin Android app, which I just reorganized slightly: I added a Portable Class Library to the solution, and I moved the business classes into that new library. After launching, though, the app now crashes at startup, and the output reports a stack overflow because the `OnCreate` method of `MyApplication` calls a native `n_onCreate` method, which in turns calls `MyApplication.OnCreate`.

I'm sincerely puzzled. I made no changes to the `OnCreate` method, nor to any part of the `MyApplication` class, and I have no idea where this infinite call loop could come from. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

`MyApplication` inherits from `Application`, overrides `OnCreate` and the `OnCreate` method calls `base.OnCreate`. Here it is:

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();

    MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(this);
}
```

I also tried to decorate the method with

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("onCreate", "()V", "GetOnCreateHandler")]
```

to no avail.

Comment: Does your MyApplication class overrides the OnCreate method? Does the OnCreate method calls base.OnCreate(); ?

Comment: Also, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: @Alexandre: MyApplication inherits from Application, overrides OnCreate and the OnCreate method calls base.OnCreate.

Comment: Have you tried to add `DoNotGenerateAcw = true` in the Register Attribute of the MyApplication class?

Comment: See this example here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2147/what-is-the-recipe-to-have-a-working-application-derived-class

Comment: DoNotGenerateAgw=true did not work :( And the discussion is the one I followed back when I implemented the OnCreate override.